# /etc/environment not work

Tags: system, etc, anaconda, environment

I declare `PATH="/usr/local/anaconda2/bin:/mnt/code/tool:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"` in `/etc/environment`.

But when I re-login,

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/hwlee/bin:/home/hwlee.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: What is the content of your `/etc/environment`?

Comment: `PATH="/usr/local/anaconda2/bin:/mnt/code/tool:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Are you manually setting `PATH` in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` or somewhere like that?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Nope I have to use only /etc/environment

Comment: @HansLee Please **[edit]** with the output of running `ls -l /etc/profile.d`, and also add the complete text of each of these files that exist (mentioning which is which) and say which ones don't exist: **`~/.pam_environment`**, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and--unless the line you showed was the whole thing, in which case please clarify that--`/etc/environment`. (One way to view the contents of a text file is with the `cat` command; for example, `cat ~/.pam_environment` outputs the contents of `~/.pam_environment`.) Thanks!